# PrimeVue 2 - Calendar - :date-select dosen't work properly - Vue.js2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, primevue

[image: 1]

I have two different calendars and I want to use the ':date-select' function on only one of them.

However, when I select a date on the calendar that doesn't have ':date-select', the 'validarDatas()' function is called for some reason.

Can someone help me with this?

Primevue2
Vue.js2

I have tried using different IDs and functions on both calendars, but when I select only one date, both functions are called.

Comment: Can you show us you're code ?

Comment: The code are in the image. can you see it or img is broken?

Link = https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ88H.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error lies in the way you call the date-select function. You could try using the following code:

```
@date-select="validarDatas('final)"
```

This should work since it is an emit. For more information on the API documentation and Vue.js emit mechanism, please refer to [1](https://primevue.org/calendar/#api.calendar.emits.date-select) and [2](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) respectively.